# Where is the microphone located?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I know the 3DS has a built in microphone somewhere, because I need to blow into it as part of a Cooking Mama 4 minigame. However. I have no idea where it is, so I just generally blow at the bottom edge of the 3DS.

I keep failing the minigame, most likely because I am blowing in the wrong spot.

Where is the microphone located, so I can blow in the right spot and get past this mini-game (because I don't like it when Mama is mad at me)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the regular 3DS, the mic is the small hole under the <kbd>Start</kbd> button.

For the 3DS XL, it is on the right of the <kbd>Start</kbd> button. It is a small hole marked  with a 'mic' label above it.

Comment: I'm surprised they moved it back to the edge... the original DS had it on the close edge toward the left side, but Nintendo moved it to the center of the hinge between the two screens for the DS Lite, DSi, and DSi XL.

Comment: Seriously? Wow. I never, ever would've noticed it there. :( I liked it better in the middle, like on the DS Lite and DSi).

Comment: They didn't even label it. It makes playing Spirit Tracks somewhat tricky, especially when trying to play the flute.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a pic I found showing you where the mic on the Nintendo 3DS is located! Hope it helps! [image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Excellent first post!  Please take the time to read the Arqade tour on the help tab.

Answer (score 3):

The 3 buttons under the touch screen(select, home, and start) is where you can locate the microphone on the 3DS. it is right under the start button but a little to the right.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure there is one beside the R button that I discovered on accident.

Comment: There could be multiple microphones used for noise cancellation, though that seems a bit strange on more of a pure-gaming thing versus a phone.